# facebook wall post encoding problem?

Tags: php, facebook, api

im using "ISO-8859-9" encoding.

my application post data to users wall but i have facebook wall post encoding problem?
i tried utf-8 encoding in wallpost.php(this is my php file for wall post) but didn't served.

What can i do?

(Sorry my first language isn't English..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find [iconv](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function.

```
$array = array(
                'name' => $burcname . ' Günlük yorumum',
                'link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/gunlukburcpaylas/sonuc.php?burc='. $burc,
                'description' => $burcname . ' Günlük yorumu. Sizde her gün profilinizde günlük burç yorumunuz için uygulamaya katılın..',
                'message' => $aciklama,
                'picture' => $picture
                );
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
            {
                $array[$key] = iconv('ISO-8859-9', 'UTF-8', $value);
            }
```